# Recursion in SQL - Common Table Expression vs WHILE

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have this table:

```
Categories( CatId, Name, ParentId NULL )
```

...which is recursive, so each category can name a parent category, which in turn has a parent, and so on. Like so:

```
1, "Sports", NULL
2, "Football", 1
3, "Golf", 1
4, "Handegg", 2
5, "Sex", NULL
6, "On the beach", 5
```

A while ago I used a CTE to perform a recursive lookup on a category's parent, like so:

```
WITH Categories(CatId, Name, ParentId, n) AS (
    SELECT CatId, Name, ParentId, 1
    FROM Categories
    WHERE CatId = @categoryId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c1.CatId, c1.Name, c1.ParentId, c2.n + 1
    FROM Categories AS c1
         INNER JOIN Categories AS c2 ON c1.CatId = c2.ParentId
)
```

But I was thinking, couldn't I rephrase that as a WHILE query?

```
DECLARE @ret TABLE( CatId, Name, ParentId )

DECLARE @tCatId int
DECLARE @tName nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @tParentId int NULL

SELECT @tCatId = CatId, @tName = Name, @tParentId = ParentId
FROM Categories
WHERE CatId = @categoryId

WHILE( @tParentId IS NOT NULL ) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ret ( CatId, Name, ParentId ) VALUES ( @tCatId, @tName, @tParentId )

    SELECT @tCatId = CatId, @tName = Name, @tParentId = ParentId
    FROM Categories
    WHERE CatId = @tParentId
END

SELECT @ret
```

Obviously it's a bit rough around the edges (such as not completing when the first row's ParentId is NULL), and I haven't been able to test it (as my SQL Server is down for a rebuild), but surely it's just as correct?

Comment: Recursive CTEs really need the recursive part to be able to be evaluated efficiently via an index or they can have [severe performance problems](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15596/sql-query-slow-down-from-1-second-to-11-minutes-why)

Answer (score 5):

While this would semantically work, CTE's are generally nicer to program with because they represent immutable, logical result sets. A while loop imperatively dictates an execution model. For that reason it is a little more work to get right and to maintain.

There is a good chance the CTE will be faster. Internally it contains a form of while loop, but that loop sits deeply in the query execution pipeline. It is much faster than a T-SQL loop. Also, it is a single statement. The while loop runs many statements. SQL Server has a small per-statement overhead (even if it is just `select null`).

That said a while loop sometimes gives you more flexibility and more control.

You probably should try to solve your requirements with a CTE first. Use imperative control flow only when you notice (or you can foresee) that a while-loop would be a better solution for some concrete reason.

Answer (score 1):

A CTE is used to represent a temporary result set using which you can write complex queries.

```
WITH DerviedTable (<Column>) AS (SELECT query to derive a table from one or more tables)
<A complex SELECT query that uses the DerviedTable one or more times>
```

In the absence of CTE, you would have to define that dervied table in all the places where you need to refer to it in JOINS.

CTE with recursion using `UNION ALL` certainly complements the `WHILE` based recursive logic but as you see, it removes the hassle to write that TSQL and just define the base and the recursive members.

In one of our previous projects on MSSQL Server, when we migrated to SQL Server 2005, we aggressively replaced all such WHILE based recursions with CTEs and ran into a deadlock situation where there were [table variables involved in CTE definition](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/527843/deadlock-hang-cpu-thrashing-when-combining-udf-cte-and-udtt). Not sure if this has been fixed in the recent versions but thought worth sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Neither are correct

In first missing
c2.CatId = @categoryId

In second
WHERE CatId = @tParentId